# Trouble with Custom Git Aliases on Windows

Tags: git, git-alias

I have these 2 aliases:

```
ctt = "!f() { $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) -ne 'develop' && git tag -a testing-$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)-$(date +'%Y%m%d')-$1 -m '$2' && git push --tags; }; f"
cpt = "!f() { [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "develop" ] && git tag -a production-$1-$(date +'%Y%m%d')-$2 -m '$3' && git push --tags; }; f"
```

So that I can do:

`git ctt BranchName rc1 "Trying to add XYZ feature"` to create tag `testing-BranchName-20240229-rc1`

`git cpt FeatureName r1 "XYZ feature release"` to create tag `production-FeatureName-20240229-r1`

I wanted ctt to only work on branches that are not `develop` and cpt to only work on `develop` so I added the condition but I get the error:

```
cpt_test = "!f() { [ "$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)" = "develop" ] && echo production-$1-$(date +'%Y%m%d')-$2 }; f"
```

```
fatal: bad config line 21 in file C:/Users/david/.gitconfig
```

I've tried escaping quotes, adding `\` to make it multiline and see if I had any error but nothing I've tried works.

I'm on Windows 11, git version 2.39.2.windows.1

Whole `.gitconfig`

```
[user]
    email = david@energia-viva.com
    name = David 
[credential "http://192.168.1.89"]
    provider = generic
[pager]
    log = false
    show = false
[alias]
    lg1 = "log --reverse --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(blue)- %an%C(reset) - %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(auto)%d%C(reset)' --all"
    lg2 = "log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold cyan)%aD%C(reset) %C(bold cyan)(%ar)%C(reset)%C(auto)%d%C(reset)%n''          %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)' --all"
    lg = !"git lg1"
    lg3 = log -10 --reverse --abbrev-commit
    files = !"git show --pretty --name-only $1 #"
    pop = !"git stash pop"
    pa = !"git push --all"
    paf = !"git push --all --force"
    dbe = !"git branch -d $1 && git push origin --delete $1 && :"
    # I've tried:
    ctt_test = "!f() { ctt 'tag message' } f"
    #ctt_test = !"f() { ctt 'tag message' ;}"
    #ctt_test = !"ctt 'tag message'"
[diff]
    tool = icdiff
[difftool]
    prompt = false
[difftool "icdiff"]
    cmd = C:/Users/david/AppData/Local/Packages/PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0/LocalCache/local-packages/python310/site-packages/icdiff.py --line-numbers $LOCAL $REMOTE
[rerere]
    enabled = true
[push]
    autoSetupRemote = true
[credential "http://git.local"]
    provider = generic
```

profile:

```
function Create-TestingTag {
    $currentBranch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

    if ($currentBranch -ne 'develop') {
        $releaseCandidateNumbers = git tag -l "testing-$currentBranch-*" | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Match($_, '(?<=testing-$currentBranch-\d{8}-)rc\d+').Value } | Sort-Object -Descending

        if ($releaseCandidateNumbers.Count -gt 0) {
            $latestReleaseCandidate = $releaseCandidateNumbers[0]
            $releaseNumber = [regex]::Match($latestReleaseCandidate, '\d+').Value
            $newReleaseCandidateNumber = [int]$releaseNumber + 1
        } else {
            $newReleaseCandidateNumber = 1
        }


        $tagName = "testing-$currentBranch-{0:yyyyMMdd}-rc$newReleaseCandidateNumber" -f (Get-Date)
        $tagMessage = $args[0]
        git tag -a $tagName -m '$tagMessage'
        git push --tags
    } else {
        Write-Output "You're not on 'develop' branch, exiting."
    }
}

function Create-ProductionTag {
    $currentBranch = git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD

    if ($currentBranch == 'develop') {
        $releaseNumbers = git tag -l 'production-*' | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Match($_, '(?<=production-\w+-\d{8}-)r\d+').Value } | Sort-Object -Descending
        
        if ($releaseNumbers.Count -gt 0) {
            $latestRelease = $releaseNumbers[0]
            $releaseNumber = [regex]::Match($latestRelease, '\d+').Value
            $newReleaseNumber = [int]$releaseNumber + 1
        } else {
            $newReleaseNumber = 1
        }

        $tagName = "production-$($args[0])-{0:yyyyMMdd}-r$newReleaseNumber" -f (Get-Date)
        $tagMessage = $args[1]
        git tag -a $tagName -m '$tagMessage'
        git push --tags
    } else {
        Write-Output "You're not on 'develop' branch, exiting."
    }
}

New-Alias -Name 'ctt' -Value 'Create-TestingTag' -Scope Global
New-Alias -Name 'cpt' -Value 'Create-ProductionTag' -Scope Global
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
cpt = "!f() { if [[ \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\" = develop ]];then echo production-$1-$(date +'%Y%m%d')-$2;fi }; f"
```

I'm not quite sure what the cause is in your version. This modified version can work in git-bash.

**Note** that it's not a valid alias name if it contains `_`. So, rename it. The shell function part needs modification too.

It would be easier to write the function in `~/.bashrc` or other similar files and call it in the alias.

In the configuration file,

```
[alias]
    cpt = "!f() { if [[ \"$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)\" = develop ]];then echo production-$1-$(date +'%Y%m%d')-$2;fi }; f"
```

Comment: Sadly does not work for me. `fatal: bad config line 21 in file C:/Users/david/.gitconfig`, I didn't know you could use .bashrc on windows, I'll try that

Comment: @Daviid I use git-bash, not CMD or PowerShell. `~/.bashrc` works in git-bash.

Comment: I use powershell with posh-git and starship

Comment: @Daviid I tried `git cpt_test foo bar` in CMD and PowerShell and both worked. It prints `production-foo-20240301-bar`. I updated my answer with the content in the configuration file.

Comment: @Daviid Besides, does `line 21` indeed refer to the cpt_test line?

Comment: I guess my PC hates me then `fatal: bad config line 20 in file C:/Users/dpareja/.gitconfig`

I've updated my main post with my whole `.gitconfig` file and also added the functions I created in my powershell profile. However I don't think I can use them on .gitconfig aliases (not a big deal I'd just rather write `git` in front of the command)

Comment: @Daviid My bad. When I tested it, I use the alias name `cpt` instead of `cpt_test`. When I answered and commented, I simply replace `cpt` with `cpt_test` and thought it didn't matter. It turns out that the alias name cannot have `_` in it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I did not know that, removing the _ fixes the "fatal: bad config" error. Your latest alias also prints correctly `production-foo-20240301-111`, Thank you.

Comment: Seems like `-` are okay

Comment: @Daviid I tried this on an Ubuntu machine with `vi` as the editor.  `vi` turns the color of the variable from cyan to white when an underscore is appended, which indicates the variable is not valid. However, invalid underscore in a configuration variable is not mentioned in the manual of git config.